# api.ai Fullfillment POST requests doesn't append the action in the POST URL

Tags: microservices, dialogflow-es

Currently all the Fulfilment requests originating from api.ai are, POST requests to the base url configured in api.ai Fulfilment section. But to be able to have proper routing (microservice style) set-up on the server side it would be more worthwhile to append the action in the POST URL.

For a substantially large project, there can be hundreds of fulfilment actions and managing all of them in single monolithic project is cumbersome. If the action comes in the URL, then we can configure and organise the actions into multiple cloudfunctions in case of firebase hosting / server side microservices.

Edit:
As answered by matthewayne, I can use my own proxy set-up to route the requests to achieve the goal. But I don't want to introduce any additional delay into the request processing. Because I am expecting huge number of webhooks being fired. This would be a very easy implementation for Google api.ai team to incorporate that allows for a greater flexibility! Hence expecting an answer from google team!

Answer (score 1):

Currently this isn't possible with API.AI's webhook design.  I'd recommend setting up a proxy service that unpacks the webhook requests from API.AI, inspects the action and sends the proper request to the proper microservice endpoint and then forwards the response back to API.AI once the microservice has returned its result:
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know that I can use my own proxy set-up to route the requests to achieve the goal. But I don't want to introduce any additional delay into the request processing. Because I am expecting huge number of webhooks being fired. This would be a very easy implementation for Google api.ai team to incorporate that allows for a greater flexibility! Hence expecting an answer from google team!